# Creating a std::function with a lambda without knowing the arguments of the function

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, std-function

I would like to create a [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) from a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), in a [`template`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates) that takes the desired instance of `std::function` as its argument :

```
template <class functionT>
functionT make_lambda() {
    return [](/* ignore all args */){ std::cout << "my lambda\n"; };
}
```

And then call that `template` with varying [aliases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) of `std::function` :

```
using function_no_args = std::function<void(void)>;
using function_args = std::function<void(int)>;

make_lambda<function_no_args>()(); // output: "my lambda"
make_lambda<function_args>()(999); // compile error
```

How can I achieve this ?

Some precisions :

- I need the ability to have aliases for the `std::function`, to define them in `traits` structures and pass them around to multiple portions of my code
- The return type will always be `void`, only the arguments may change

Comment: Do you simply want your lambda to be callable with any kind of arguments, or do you need your lambda to only be callable with arguments that correspond to the signature of the `std::function` and have everything else fail to compile?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel I'd want it to be callable with the arguments of the signature (I won't call function_args without passing an int)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use a generic lambda with a parameter pack to swallow and ignore whatever arguments may be given to it:

```cpp
template <class functionT>
functionT make_lambda() {
    return [](auto&&...){ std::cout << "my lambda\n"; };
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept a different way to call

```
make_lambda<function_no_args>::func()();
make_lambda<function_args>::func()(999);
```

You can make `make_lambda` a functional using template specialization

```
template <typename>
struct make_lambda;

template <typename ... Args>
struct make_lambda<std::function<void(Args...)>>
 {
   static std::function<void(Args...)> func ()
    { return [](Args ...){ std::cout << "my lambda\n"; }; }
 };
```